# vertical align text of unknown width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have text div inside an article that is brought in through Wordpress. (layout is using Bootstrap 3 framework) The div enlarges when .linkage is hovered over. Everything works fine (centred horizontally, grows from the center of the text) except its aligned to the top of the article. I tried the various ways of vertically centred but can't seem to get it to work.

HTML

```
<article class='col-md-12'>
    <div class="bg-img" style="background-image:url('...');">
        <a href="#" class="linkage"></a>
        <!-- Put cat div overtop article -->
        <div class="cat-cell">
            <div class="cat-border">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <h2><?php the_category(' | '); ?></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cover"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- / bg-img -->
</article>
```

CSS
    article {
      position: absolute;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

```
.bg-img {
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.cat-border { 
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #fff; 
}

.cat-cell {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  opacity: 0; 
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;

  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;    
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.linkage:hover + .cat-cell {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  -o-transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CSS article { position: absolute; margin-bottom: 10px; }

if you want to use absolute positioning(which is unusual..)

try:

```
article { position: absolute;
          top:50%;
          transform: translateY(-50%)
          }
```

if you want to also center it horizontally:

```
article { position: absolute;
          top:50%;
          left:50%;
          transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
          }
```

Comment: I was getting close using absolute positioning, I have to add margin:auto, but its not quite centred. Seems like transform:translate isn't doing anything for me

Comment: can you make a fiddle or give link to live site, it's hard to just guess :) , BTW if you use absolute positioning margins won't respond..

Comment: when I changed it to absolute and added margins it got it more centred, internet references mention to use it. Unfortunately I haven't been able to recreate it in jsfiddle because of Wordpress/bootstrap

Comment: I'm sorry,  they do react, but It's usually better to use `top:` `left:` `right:` `bottom:` properties, so you don't mix positioning parameters

Comment: I tried your code but the only thing that is getting me close is when i add    top: 50%; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;  margin: auto;

Comment: try  `{top:50%; left:50%;transform: translate(-50%,-50%); margin: 0;}` (might need to reset margins)

Comment: I gotta keep margins to auto or it pulls to much to one side, I've got it to the point where I need transform: translateY(-50%) but it's not working. It vert centres to the top of the div with    top: 50%; right: 0; left: 0;
margin: 0 auto;

Comment: I got a different technique to work (albeit by accident) you put me on the right trail, thanks for the help!